# Getting methods on an instance

Tags: javascript

From the following code:

```js
let n = 1234.567;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number.prototype));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(n));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(5));
```

The first `console.log` prints the properties, but the second and third line just print `{}`. Why is this so? Is there a name to directly inspect the variable or number without having to refer to the base type, such as `Number.prototype` ?

Comment: StackOverflow's snippet console shows properties which are enumerable. The properties that you're trying to see are not enumerable. So you need to use your browsers console to see them

Answer (score 1):

The second and third line only appear to print empty objects due to how the Stack Snippet console operates - the actual browser console of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or whatever browser you wish will be much more informative. When debugging things and logging *objects*, if you want the most informative interface, use the actual browser console.

Both of those lines really do point to `Number.prototype`:

[image]

```js
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(5) === Number.prototype
);
```